# How do I instruct Git to show help without any pager-based documentation system, be it info or man?

Tags: command-line, git, cygwin

By default, on unix systems, git displays help through `man`, which requires it to load a pager, ruining my workflow. When I type `git branch --help`, I want it to display the options, in a short summary. I am accustommed to typing `--help` after a command for summaries and typing `man <command>` for the manpage. I don't need a manpage when I ask for a summary of options. How do I instruct Git to use `--help` for summaries instead of `-h`?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12166295/disable-all-paging-in-git
-- There are answers there to disable the help pager: (1) change git config's `man.viewer` (and also define its `.cmd`); (2) change your environment's `$MANPAGER` setting to something like `PAGER=cat`. But the git's `--help` output still shows the long help, not the short help from `-h`.

Comment: This solution would work well if the manpage `Options` part was short. That way, I could use awk to print only the `Options` part, and that would be the end of it. But unfortunately, the `Options` part has very long descriptions suitable only for pagers.

Answer (score 2):

(1) Modify the option processing in the git source, and recompile it. You'll need to redo this whenever you upgrade git.

(2) Write a wrapper that gets called instead of the real binary (by putting it first in the `PATH`, or by renaming the `git` binary), which then swaps `--help` with `-h` and calls the original binary.

If you are looking for an easy solution like "just set this configuration, and it will do it in my special way that only I need and nobody else": you probably won't find it. If you want to customize software for your personal specific needs, you need to work for it.

Comment: The configuration way of customization has the added functionality of being both predictable and manageable over time, plus, all the GNU coreutils print to stdout instead of using a pager for the `--help` argument, it seems that git is the odd one out in this situation. Take a look at this [GNU Coding Standards page](https://www.gnu.org/prep/standards/html_node/_002d_002dhelp.html)

Answer (score 0):

Go to the man page directly.
Less is needed for a proper formatting.

```
 $ man git-diff | less | head -n 15

GIT-DIFF(1)                                                     Git Manual                                                     GIT-DIFF(1)

NAME
       git-diff - Show changes between commits, commit and working tree, etc

SYNOPSIS
       git diff [<options>] [<commit>] [--] [<path>...]
       git diff [<options>] --cached [--merge-base] [<commit>] [--] [<path>...]
       git diff [<options>] [--merge-base] <commit> [<commit>...] <commit> [--] [<path>...]
       git diff [<options>] <commit>...<commit> [--] [<path>...]
       git diff [<options>] <blob> <blob>
       git diff [<options>] --no-index [--] <path> <path>

DESCRIPTION
       Show changes between the working tree and the index or a tree, changes between the index and a tree, changes between two trees,
```

You can also modify using some filter to print up to `DESCRIPTION` instead of using `head`

Comment: Of course, this is indeed a working solution, however this question is related more closely to my workflow. I am accustomed to typing `--help` as an argument when I want a short but descriptive summary. However git implements the same feature in the `-h` argument. The GNU Coreutils are part of my workflow and they all print a descriptive summary about the options to stdout without loading any complicated pager. Git chooses to be the odd one out, and I want to mitigate that exact behaviour of Git

Comment: Plus, I think man automatically formats the manpage when it detects a pipe, less is not needed in this situation, try `diff <(man git-diff) <(man git-diff | less)` and see for yourself. Also, less is a pager, man uses troff for formatting

Comment: @Monke without `less` I have escape artifact on my Mintty terminal. `Less` solved it.

Comment: That is very peculiar